# Multipart message sent as text/plain instead multipart/alternative in java

Tags: java, jakarta-mail, mime, multipart

I am sending a message as multipart and below is my code:

```
Message message = new MimeMessage(session);
Multipart multiPart = new MimeMultipart("alternative");

try {

MimeBodyPart textPart = new MimeBodyPart();
textPart.setText(text, "utf-8");

MimeBodyPart htmlPart = new MimeBodyPart();
htmlPart.setContent(html, "text/html; charset=utf-8");

multiPart.addBodyPart(htmlPart);
multiPart.addBodyPart(textPart);
message.setContent(multiPart);
transport.send(message);

} catch (AddressException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    System.out.println("Error: "+e.getMessage());

}
```

Now when I receive it in outlook it is shown as **text/plain**

Any ideas?

Comment: How does it display in other mailers such as Thunderbird?  What does the message look like if you add `message.writeTo(System.out)` before the transport.send call?

Comment: if I `System.out.println(message.getContentType());` it displays **text/plain**

Comment: You need to call `message.saveChanges()` before doing that to get a valid result.

Comment: I found it yesterday and saw your comment today about the same. Thanks @BillShannon It worked.

Answer (score 1):

I finally found solution to this issue. Apparently sometimes you need to save changes to make your message sent as multipart/alternative. I referred to:

https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/mail/Message.html#saveChanges()

So now my code is:

```
Message message = new MimeMessage(session);
Multipart multiPart = new MimeMultipart("alternative");

try {

MimeBodyPart textPart = new MimeBodyPart();
textPart.setText(text, "utf-8");

MimeBodyPart htmlPart = new MimeBodyPart();
htmlPart.setContent(html, "text/html; charset=utf-8");

multiPart.addBodyPart(htmlPart);
multiPart.addBodyPart(textPart);
message.setContent(multiPart);
message.saveChanges();
transport.send(message);

} catch (AddressException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    System.out.println("Error: "+e.getMessage());

}
```

Comment: The saveChanges call should not be necessary unless you're using a **very** old version of JavaMail.  What version are you using?  Also, note that your [transport instance is not being used](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/FAQ#commonmistakes).